# Attempting to Draw Electricity Grid - Need Maximum Segment Length and Precise GPS Coordinates

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am attempting to draw an electricity grid (poles and cables) using QGIS. I need to ensure that each pole is a maximum of 50m apart, and then I need to measure the total length of the grid and identify the precise location of all poles. See my screenshot below for what it looks like - the yellow lines are electricity cable, the red dots are poles, and blue dots are houses.

I'm using the Advanced Digitizing tool to limit my line segments to be <=50m and Vector > Geometry > Extract Vertices to generate the pole locations. However, when I look at the attribute table for my poles shapefile, there are no GPS coordinates attached to my red dots (poles). This information is critical. How can I get GPS coordinates (ideally lat/long in decimal degrees) for the poles?

Is there a better way for me to do this? I need to draw a utility grid where no line segment exceeds 50m, and I need precise GPS coordinates of each pole.

[image]

Comment: First things first: Have you had any education when it comes to how poles & cables are built/placed? Because this looks rather wild.

Comment: When Coordinate Reference System us your data stored in?

Comment: @StuSmith I am using Africa_Equidistant_Conic EPSG:102023

Comment: @Erik thanks for that constructive feedback

Comment: @StuSmith I am using Africa_Equidistant_Conic EPSG:102023 on my line segments because I need to use a "projected coordinate system" in order to use the CAD design tools which allow me to limit line segment lengths to 50m

After I extract the pole locations, I convert that layer into EPSG 4326 but it's not capturing the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

I was able to obtain GPS coordinates for my pole locations by using Vector > Geometry Tools > Add Geometry Attributes to geotag each pole with x and y coordinates